# Multiple maker title is not showing in google map in swift 5

Tags: swift

I am using google map in swift 5. I have to show all marker title.But only one marker title shows in google map.here is screen shot
[image]
 Here is my code..

```
for x in myarr{
    let marker = GMSMarker()        
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x.lat, x.lon)
    marker.title = x.name
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "item_car_idle")
    self.googleMap.selectedMarker = marker
    marker.map =  self.googleMap
}
```

I think last marker title will show. How to show all the marker title in swift.
Please help me

Comment: What does  `myarr` contain?

Comment: @PGDev  it shows on tabbed marker the title. I want to show all title without tab

Comment: Add the screenshot of the actual and expected output.

Comment: @PGDev I have already updated a screen shoot.

Comment: How many elements are there in `myarr` and what do you mean by "show all title without tab"?

Comment: @PGDev Yes sir, I want to show all title without tap

Comment: @PGDev maker  tap action will work

Comment: @PGDev  there is aciotn ontab marker

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `marker` to take tap actions, then set

```
marker.tappable = false
```